# Another implementation of WPF Event to Command (with problems)

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, icommand

I am looking at various implementations of hooking a ICommand up to a control's event. So for instance the GotFocus of a TextBox should call a GotFocusCommand in my View Model. I then got an idea to implement my own version (for my own learning) and it is working well, but I can only link one event to one command in the XAML.

( Basically I just use reflection to find the specified Event and then do a AddEventHandler that executes the command )

This works fine :

```
<Button 
  local:EventToCommand.Event="Click" 
  local:EventToCommand.Command="{Binding TestCommand}" 
  />
```

But this does not :

```
<Button 
  local:EventToCommand.Event="Click" 
  local:EventToCommand.Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
  local:EventToCommand.Event="GotFocus" 
  local:EventToCommand.Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}"
  />
```

as you it leads to a duplicate attribute name error.

Would it be possible to do something like :

```
<Button>
  <Some Xaml Element>
    <local:EventToCommand Event="Click" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
    <local:EventToCommand Event="GotFocus" Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}" />
  </Some Xaml Element>
</Button>
```

to "map" multiple events to commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this, either using an Attached Property or inheriting from Button and adding your own DependencyProperty that contains a list of EventToCommand objects, and when you add to that collection you wire up the event to command. If this seems confusing, I can try to whip up some examples.

C#

```
    public class EventedButton : Button
{
    public static DependencyProperty EventCommandsProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("EventCommands", typeof(EventToCommandCollection), typeof(EventedButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public EventToCommandCollection EventCommands
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(EventCommandsProperty) as EventToCommandCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(EventCommandsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public EventedButton()
    {
        this.EventCommands = new EventToCommandCollection(this);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
    <local:EventedButton>
        <local:EventedButton.EventCommands>
            <local:EventToCommand />
        </local:EventedButton.EventCommands>
    </local:EventedButton>
```

Inside of EventToCommandCollection, you would attach/detach to the Event you wanted when items are added to the collection.

UPDATE: Attached Property

Here is some code to do the collection as an attached property:

C#

```
        public static DependencyProperty CommandsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Commands",
        typeof(ICollection<EventToCommand>),
        typeof(DependencyObject),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandsChanged));


    private static void OnCommandsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Attach/Detach event handlers
    }

    public static void SetCommands(DependencyObject element, ICollection<EventToCommand> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CommandsProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICollection<EventToCommand> GetCommands(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ICollection<EventToCommand>)element.GetValue(CommandsProperty);
    }
```

Xaml:

```
    <local:EventedButton>
        <local:EventToCommand.Commands>
            <local:EventToCommandCollection>
                <local:EventToCommand/>
            </local:EventToCommandCollection>
        </local:EventToCommand.Commands>
    </local:EventedButton>
```

Comment: My current implementation is based on Attached Properties as Event & Command are both AP's. I am not sure whoever how to use that implementation to specify multiple EventToCommand's in XAML. The inheritance option)

Comment: The inheritance option is fine, but how would I initialize the EventToCommand collection in XAML ?

Comment: Thanks mekansm. We've been focussing on Button here, but obviously I would like to "override" any event from any UI element, I assume though that I could just inheret from the relevant UI element base class. Is there a solution that works without the inheritance though ? Or how would I initialize/add-entries the collection in XAML ?

Comment: I updated again with the attached property version. Key is the         <local:EventToCommandCollection> tag. This will create a new collection for you. In my prototype I through together to test this, EventToCommandCollection was just a List<EventToCommand> with no special code.

Comment: Your example is still based on a button though. Could this collection be implemented standalone so that it can be applied to any control ?

Comment: It will work for any DependencyObject (the third parameter of the DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached lets you know the types it can be applied to).

Comment: And a great deal of thanks for the standalone implementation without depending on the Blend SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Blend Event Triggers and an action negates the need to handle your own collections.
And it can be added to any control.

See MVVM Lights [EventToCommand](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

Or my extension of it [here.](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/)[(source)](http://present.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Blog/EventToCommand.cs)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not have Blend, so I do not have the Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity dll ....

Answer (score 0):

GalaSoft MVVM Light ToolKit - EventToCommand you can do this

```
<Button> 
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
      <cmd:EventToCommand 
          PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
           Command="{Binding ButtonClick}"
       />
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus" >
      <cmd:EventToCommand 
          PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
           Command="{Binding ButtonGotFocus}"
       />
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Where import this namespaces

```
 i- xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;
    assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
 cmd-xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
     assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```